# Developer trying to delete a field in a managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

We are developing an upgrade to a managed package and want to delete a custom field on the Contact object.  There is no option to delete it.  Are there are any suggestions to delete or hide the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete a custom field after releasing a Managed Package. In the ISV docs there is a chart showing what objects are Customer/Developer Editable and Deleteable. Custom fields are no by both parties as far as ability to delete.

You can certainly make a new page layout and not include that field. Additionally you can edit the profile and/or Permission set (since you are referring to Contact which is a Standard object it would be the Profile in this case) and make the field inaccessible by that profile.

Those are your only options.

Comment: I'm confused the doc here says they're developer deletable on page 29: https://na15.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

Comment: The initial question was posted 7 months ago. You are reading the current, Spring 14, Salesforce release notes. Salesforce has since added the ability to do this. It was not available before this release.